# Java SE 7 Certification sample task not understandable

Tags: java, certificate

I am reading about the Oracle Java SE 7 Certified Programmer Level 2. I looked at the sample questions on their [website](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=303&p_certName=SQ1Z0_804) and found this one which answer I cannot understand.

```
import java.util.*; 
public class MyScan { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      String in = "1 a 10 . 100 1000"; 
      Scanner s = new Scanner(in); 
      int accum = 0; 
      for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++) { 
        accum += s.nextInt(); 
      } 
      System.out.println(accum); 
   } 
}
```

What is the result?  
A) 1 
B) 11 
 C) 111 
 D) 1111 
 E) Compilation fails. 
 F) Class2 has-a
   Class1.   
G) An exception is thrown at run time

The right answer is F. What does that answer mean?

Comment: That *they* should improve their content review process. Answer F is clearly unrelated to the question.

Comment: I agree with @Andreas_D. After just trying it, G) seems to be the correct answer...

Comment: Btw: yet another good reason for thinking twice before paying for certifications like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would receive an Exception at Run Time.

```
 java.util.InputMismatchException
```

It is because, it fails during second iteration when it tries to match `a`